# Please help, I can't access my pc after bad upgrade

Tags: system

as above my system has failed.

I was using 14, when I was given the option to upgrade to 15. During the installation it froze, therefore I had no option but to restart.

It now just boots to a basic looking terminal and asks for 'login'.

Before I did the upgrade I made a system restore point, is there any way of using it through the live cd?

I also don't mind re-installing, however some of my files don't appear when using live cd.

Any help appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

What Ubuntu version were you using before? Ubuntu 14.04.x? Also how did you create a system restore point? To my knowledge this is not possible using Ubuntu.

I'd recommend creating a bootable USB medium (instructions for [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)) using [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) ISO and launching the live environment from it. When you have booted into the live environment, backup all your files and configs on a separate hard drive and just reinstall Ubuntu 16.04, replacing all other Ubuntu installations.

Comment: Thanks Flatron, I'm actually in the process of doing just that.